How to integrate FME and ACC to GET ISSUE from a project
I am using FME to get all issues from ACC. I am using HTTPCaller in that case. I used HTTPCaller to get ACC token, and Project successfully, but once I am using this transformer to get all issues in "_response_body" it is giving me the html file with no result istead of Jason
"<!doctype html><"
I have attached the process of transformers I used plus the last HTTPCaller I used based on this link 
I tried HTTPCaller and even AutoDeskDocsConnector but it did not worked so far
